# Is is possible to pretty-print output JSON in hapi-swagger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, hapi.js, pretty-print

I'm using hapi-swagger (https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger) to generate Swagger docs for my API. I get the ability to try out the APIs via the browser using this as well, which is great. The problem is that the results of the API call are in a compact format--large JSON structures on a single line. It makes sense that the API should produce output like this, but I would like the swagger web client to pretty-print it for me.

I note that regular Swagger seems to be able to do this, based on my reading of this issue (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/810) but I'm unsure if it's possible to pass along options that get that same behavior in hapi-swagger.

Is it possible, and if so, how do I do it?